# Using @top-left and other to print headers and footers

Tags: css

I have a react app that I would like to print a page as PDF with certain content for header and footer. I have seen some solutions involve including divs that you place in the correct position with absolute or fixed, or other have a table where they place the header content and the top and footer content at the bottom.

My question is how do I use @top-left or @top-right or @bottom-left etc, to add content to the header and footer of the printed PDF.

I have tried the following

```
@media print {
  @page {
    margin: 2cm; /* Set page margins */
    size: A4; /* Set page size */
    @top-center {
      content: "Header Content"; /* Define header content */
    }
    @bottom-center {
      content: "Footer Content - Page " counter(page); /* Define footer content with page number */
    }
    @top-left {
      content: "test";
    }
  }
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  ul {
    background-color: green;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  button {
    padding-block: var(--margin-l);
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-on-primary);
  }
}
```

All parts in the code above work, except for the content not showing for the header and footer. The @top-left and so on has been released since 2011, they should work. Please, any suggested work arounds with tables and such are not welcome. There should be a way to use these properties to add content to the printed PDF header and footer.